# ng-click under ng-repeat under Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat  under that

i have ng-click

like

```
<div ng-repeat="">
  <div ng-click="someFunction(name)"></div>
<input type="text" class="common btnDarkGrey editDashboardCategory" data-ng-model="inputCategory" ng-hide="!item.show">
</div>
```

Now my code

```
$scope.someFunction = function(name) {
      $scope.scroller.items[index].show = true;
    $scope.inputCategory=name;
    });
```

Which is working fine on very first click.

When i click second time. my first div pick second value

Any idea ? how to do this

Thanks

Comment: Missing var? `var new_name = `.

Comment: You have probably mixed the scopes. You will have to post more code - ideally a fiddle/plunk to get more detailed help.

Comment: You want individual `showName` per div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want individual `showName` values per rendered row you need to set it to individual child scope. Right now you are setting the value to the parent scope `showName` which is shared by all child scopes `ngRepeat` creates.

The simple fix is to refer child scope with `this` keyword:

```
$scope.someFunction = function(name) {
    var new_name = /* some other calculations */
    this.showName = new_name;
};
```